# Rails 3 - Store and open pdf files in Rails directory when using Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I need to use some pdf files for my Rails app. As they're few and not very heavy, I'm keeping them in my Rails app directory. For example, if 1.pdf file is in Rails root, I use `open("#{Rails.root}/1.pdf")` to open it. This works locally, but when I push to Heroku, all pdf files get ignored. Should I put them in a specific directory so Heroku doesn't get rid of them? I've tried with Rails root, public, and app. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the files are included in your get repository?

Comment: They show up in Github, but when I look for them using the heroku console, they are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had specified the `.slugignore` file to ignore all pdf files.